# Magento2 - can I remove meta keywords from admin for categories and products?

Tags: magento2, meta-keywords

I would like to remove meta keywords as a database field for categories and products.

This will just make it simpler for the client and make it less likely that the meta title gets wrongly placed in the wrong box.

Comment: you can try to get the template 'add product' put in your theme and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Under attribute sets edit screens move meta keywords to unassigned.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/attribute-sets.html

This will remove it from edit screen.

Comment: I get "You can't remove attributes from this attribute set." if I try that with M2.